# Cordova WebSQL - onSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, web-sql

I'm new to Cordova and currently working with it. I'm creating a login script at the moment, but when I submit a form it looks like the database won't react.

The following is what I'm trying to do:

1. When the API's are loaded, create a table and insert a record.
2. When user submits the form, check if the inserted data equals the data of the table.
3. If it matches, go to a new page.

I'm not even getting the alert `invalid ...` when I inserted something useless. I'm getting the `success!` alert when I start-up the app.

HTML:

```
<form id="login" onsubmit="check_login();" class="form-signin">
    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Sign in
    </button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var db;

function check_login() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE username=? AND password=?', [username, password], function(tx, results) {
            if (results.rows) {
                window.location = "main.html";
            } else {
                alert("Invalid username or password");
            }
        }, null);
    });
}

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOGIN');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGIN (id unique, username, password)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGIN (id, username, password) VALUES (1, "Admin", "Admin")');
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}
```

Comment: From docs: _The rowsAffected is always 0 for a SQL select statement. For insert or update statements it returns the number of modified rows._ So use `if (results.rows)` instead.

Comment: ah thanx!! will update that, tried it in the code, but my code isn't getting to the if statement. so the question still remains.

Comment: Do you get errors in console during `check_login` execution? Are sure `function(tx, results)` is executed (you can check it by setting `alert` at its beginning or by replacing `null` with `errorCB`)?

Comment: No errors in the log. the alert in function(tx, results) isn't executed ! even errorCB wont hit

Comment: Is `check_login` executed at all? Check it (by setting `alert` in this function beginning). If no, try to use `<form id="login" action="" onsubmit="check_login();return false;" class="form-signin">`

Comment: you are right to be looking at the default event of the submit button. I already tried and solved my question :) thank for helping me :)

Comment: You're welcome. `results.rows.length` is indeed correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it ! first i needed to prevent the default event of the submit button. second i didn't think `results.row` was enough but this will do `if (results.rows.length > 0)`.

The code i use at the moment: works great !

```
function check_login() {
        event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            alert(tx + "test");
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE username=? AND password=?', [username, password], function(tx, results) {
                 if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                    window.location = "main.html";
                 } else {
                    alert("Invalid username or password");
                 }
            }, errorCB);
        });
    }
```